# How do I find words starting with a specific letter and delete that row?

Tags: vba, excel

What macro should I use to locate all rows starting with D and deleting those rows. 
Right now I'm using: (Deletes every text above TOTAL) which doesn't always work perfectly.

```
Sub A2a_Deleterowsabove()
Dim foundOne As Range
On Error Resume Next
With ActiveSheet
    Set foundOne = .Range("A:A").Find(what:="TOTAL", After:=.Range("a1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                                LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                                SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)
    If foundOne.Row > 1 Then
        Range(.Range("e1"), foundOne.Offset(-1, 0)).EntireRow.delete shift:=xlUp
    Else

End If
End With
End Sub
```

I was thinking of using this:

```
Sub Delete_Cells_with_D()
Dim i As Integer
For i = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
If Cells(i, 1) = "D* -" Then Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
Next i
End Sub
```

What should I put in the highlighted portion of the macro #2 to indicate that the numbers behind that D is unknown?

[image: Excel example, and Macros #2]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `If Cells(i,1) Like "D*" Then ...`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Sub Delete_Cells_with_D()

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row To 1 Step -1
        If Left(Cells(i, 1), 1) = "D" Then Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlUp
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Amazing! that's it! Thanks, Thomas. Just wondering if you can explain to me though what I did wrong with my macros? I noticed that you changed it to this <If Left(Cells(i, 1), 1)> Can you explain what this means? is the last 1 the variable? thanks!

Comment: The Left function returns the leftmost portion of the string.  The second parameter tells it how many characters to return.

Comment: ohh i think I understand now. Thanks for explaining it to me, Thomas. So (Cells(i,1),) means within the cell (i) is the integer D and 1),1) is how many character spaces are after the integer? Getting confused at the 1),1) part

Comment: Cells(I,1) is just the string value.  Here is another example Left("Hello World", 5  ) will return "Hello"

Comment: and it'd be 5 cause it's World's got 5 letters?

Comment: It's 5 because the first five letters of "Hello World" is "hello"